# Document position in a huge list

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Let's say we have 1 million documents in Azure Search and I order them by one index, is there a way to pick one document from the list and know the order position of the selected document?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not following what you are asking.  When you say "order" are you referring to the order position of an item from a set of search results?

Comment: Yes, that's right, the order position of an item from the search results.

Comment: Great, that helps, so if you pick a random item from this result, you can take the Key for this item and then find it in the JSON document of search results to get the position it is in.   Are you doing this in C#?  JavaScript?  If I am still on track with what you are looking for, perhaps I can help with some sample code.

Comment: Yes, I am doing this in C#, not sure how to query one item from an ordered list and get it's position as well. A sample would be great thanks :)

Comment: Hi @LiamCavanagh do you have a sample code in c# for this use case?